# Openfiledialog and Folderbrowserdialog in the same method?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `ListBox` which loads files inside a certain folder to run/open when checked. 
currently i have 2 different method: **Add click event** who add files and **Add Directory click event** who add folder and recursively add all the files.

Currently this is my 2 buttons click events:

```
private void btnAddfiles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetFolderToAddFilesFrom();
}

private void btnAddDir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetFolderToAddFilesFrom();
}
```

now what i want to do is handle this  2 options in the same method, i.e also add several or lonely file and also add folder and recursive add all the files from this folder and sub folders.

Add file function:

```
       foreach (String file in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
        {
            System.IO.Stream stream;
            try
            {
                if ((stream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    int numberOfFiles = openFileDialog1.SafeFileNames.Length;
                    using (stream)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Add directory:

```
   try
    {
        foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            yield return file;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    { }
```

Comment: Are you looking for one dialog which can handle both cases? If not just register both buttons to the same event handler and check the sender

Comment: That's awkward UI.  Maybe you ought to leave a tip for the user in a label: "You can select more than one file by holding down the Shift key while clicking the mouse or by pressing Ctrl+A".  Drag+drop from an Explorer window would be easier as well.

Comment: I want to have the option to choose folder and recursive add all the files, sometimes that a lot of files

Answer (score 3):

```
// Somewhere in you form constructor
btnAddFiles.Click += new EventHandler(btnAdd_Click);
btnAddDir.Click += new EventHandler(btnAdd_Click);

// ...

private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    GetFolderToAddFilesFrom();
}
```

Comment: Where i need to register to this 2 events ?

Comment: @user2214609: "`// Somewhere in you form constructor`"

Comment: Can i do all the add files job from the same method without separate the 2 states  with IF and ELSE ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to do. Maybe edit your question and post more code will be helpful?

Comment: @user2214609: Nothing's wrong with an `if else` statement. However, if you want to change your code to make it more concise or whatever, I suggest you to try it and ask a new question on SO in case you encounter some difficulties.